# Can we use "happenings" as a synonym for "incidents"?

Tags: synonyms

When I was writing notes for chapter 2 of "Treasure Island" as part of my studying for my upcoming English exam, I wrote, winter is when the happenings of chapter 2 take place. I quickly scrubbed it out and placed incidents rather than happenings. Then I thought to myself, is it ok to use "happenings" with an "s" instead of incidents. So I went to a thesaurus and checked that "happening" is one of the synonyms of "incident". So my question is can I use "happening" with an "s" as in "happenings" as a synonym for "incident"?

Comment: Synonyms are not identical twins, but siblings. Happenings is a vague term for the actions in an adventure novel. Incidents is closer.

Comment: thanks but this wasn't my question.

Answer (score 3):

You are unlikely to come across a reputable dictionary not giving just the bland and obvious

- '*happening*: something that happens / has happened; an event / occurrence'

definition for the primary sense. And then the 'extravaganza' sense.

This is misleading, not reflecting the restrictions found with the use of 'happening/s'.

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/happening) rightly gives a caveat:

> - Happenings are things that happen, often in a way that is unexpected or hard to explain.

There can also be a sense that the events are amusing and/or interesting/exciting. I'd say that  this is true for for chapter 2 of "Treasure Island". Yes, 'happenings' works here, while 'incidents' somehow seems out of register for a historical reference. But note that most people would use 'events' here.

In passing, Cobuild classes 'happening/s' as a count noun. I dispute this, as '3/17/a couple of happenings' isn't idiomatic. But it can certainly be used in singular or plural form.

Comment: Thank you Mr.Ashworth. I understood the second paragraph but I didn't quite understand the last one could you please explain it a bit more? (and just a side note, I had an English teacher once who also had Ashworth as his last name. It looks like your family is high up in the English education stands.)

Comment: Perhaps a good place to start is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/94618/count-vs-mass-where-can-you-look-this-up/94628#94628). // [This answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202785/what-is-the-name-for-a-single-item-of-hundreds-and-thousands/202788#202788) goes deeper. // [And this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/174610/sufferings-is-plural-though-it-is-uncountable-but-how/174618#174618) is comprehensive and correspondingly difficult.